# error: package com.linkedin.platform does not exist when adding linkedin plugin to Ionic3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, linkedin-api

I have added linkedin plugin to my ionic app and now I am getting errors when I try to run ionic app in android.

> error: package com.linkedin.platform does not exist

I have tried adding `compile files('src/main/libs/linkedin.jar')` in `'\node_modules\cordova-plugin-linkedin\src\android\LinkedIn.gradle'` file. as mention in this [link](https://github.com/zyra/cordova-plugin-linkedin/issues/44).

I have also tried adding these 2 lines in `cordova-plugin-linkedin/plugin.xml`

```
<resource-file src="src/android/linkedin.jar" target="libs/linkedin.jar" reference="true"/>
<lib-file src="src/android/linkedin.jar"/>
```

But, It didn't help. Please guide me what to do and how to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding it to

> platforms/android/cordova-plugin-linkedin/www-LinkedIn.gradle

The file should have:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
  compile files('src/main/libs/linkedin.jar')  
}
```